# Prioritize avif format with background-image css property

Tags: css, image, background-image, avif

I refactored my app with avif format for phone devices (even if it's not supported everywhere).

This code works perfectly, it prioritize avif format if it's supported by the browser:

```html
<picture>
   <source srcset="image.avif" media="(max-width:500px)" type="image/avif" />
   <img src="image.jpg" alt="nice dog" />
</picture>
```

But I also got some images as `background-image` css property. I tried the [image-set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-set()) property but without success.

```css
div {
  background-image: -webkit-image-set(
        url('image.avif') type("image/avif"),
        url('image.jpg') type("image/jpeg"));
  background-image: image-set(
        url('image.avif') type("image/avif"),
        url('image.jpg') type("image/jpeg"));
}
```

I looked at the example 2 [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/#image-set-notation).
Even Firefox nor chrome doesn't interpret well this code. Any idea ? Am I trying something that is still in draft for browsers ?

Comment: Great to see some proactive support for a greater variety of image formats, +1.

Answer (score 8):

You had the right clue. The image-set property does not yet support the type declaration. This is currently part of the CSS4 draft version which you also linked: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-4/

For right now, I am simply converting my images to AVIF with https://avif.io/ and use a detection script to add an "avif" class into my HTML. Then it's as simple as:

```
.image {background-image:url("image.jpg")}
.webp .image {background-image:url("image.webp")}
.avif .image {background-image:url("image.avif")}
```

There are several types of detection scripts:

- https://dev.to/nucliweb/detect-avif-image-support-to-use-in-your-css-4pen
- https://github.com/djpogo/avif-webp-css-support
- https://avif.io/blog/tutorials/use-avif-in-css/ (soon up)

Another hacky way would be to make a media query for the content-visibility feature, as it launched with the same versions that AVIF support in Chrome and Opera was released. However I wouldn't rely on that on a production app.

Hope this helped you out. :)

Comment: Update 2024: Note that avif.io doest not exist anymore. Try https://squoosh.app/